# Scheduled flow of tasks

Tags: java

I need to create a scheduled task of retrieving data from somewere and then perform parsing -->then manipulations --> then creating output file --> then sending output file

I would like to use 5 working classes: MainExecutor class, Retriever class, Reader class, Builder class, Sender class
The main MainExecutor class would use *ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor* for scheduling the Retriever.

I would like to make this app scalable. Do I need to make each of these classes (Reader, Builder, Sender) a separate thread?

Do I need to use a thread pool for each of them?

What is the best way to implement this program?

Comment: Depends on the data dependencies they have on each other, no?

Answer (score 0):

Retriever and Sender will presumably block waiting for the network, Reader must be IO-intensive, and Builder is probably CPU-intensive. So yes, it makes sense to run them on different threads. You need only one thread pool for all of them.

This would make your app more scalable, and would also improve the performance (throughput). The downside is that you need to organize the communication between the threads.